# Python version of c++ pointer to member?

Tags: python, c++, pointer-to-member

Consider this C++ code:

```
class TestClass{
public:
  int memberA = 0;
  int memberB = 0;  
};


void doSomethingToMember(int TestClass::* memberPointer, std::vector<TestClass> objects){
  for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)
    (objects[i].*memberPointer)++;
}
```

We have a function that accepts multiple objects and we want to perform an operation on a member we define using the `memberPointer`. How would we do this in python? I assume we can use some sort of reflection or is there a better way?

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers, but *everything* acts as a reference. This would simply be `for obj in list_of_objects: obj.member_a += 1`

Comment: Check [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2002-November/018828.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do the same in Python, you could use the `getattr` and `setattr` functions with *member name* instead of a member pointer:

```
def do_something_to_member(member_name, objects):
    for object in objects:
        member_value = getattr(object, member_name)
        setattr(object, member_name, member_value + 1)
```